# Message in didReceiveMemoryWarning in iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Is it advisable or even allowed to add a message to prompt user to restart the app before the app receive memory warning? Why yes and why no?

Comment: apple application submission guidelines does not say so..you need to ask this ques to apple directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why the question was voted down - seems like a perfectly reasonable thing to ask.

As far as I'm aware, Apple are not keen on the idea of users thinking of exiting apps (or in fact thinking about any of the background stuff which developers need to be aware of) - it's just supposed to happen. You'll get a memory warning when you start running out of memory, and you've got the chance to do something about it, so that the user is blissfully unaware of any potential problems. Look for other posts about what to do using `viewDidUnload`, which can get called in low memory situations (as well as `didReceiveMemoryWarning`).

When you're new to iPhone developing, it can seem ok to tell users that you're quitting the app, or that it's getting low on memory, but on the whole I'd have to agree with Apple, and most people just don't want to know, and just expect the app to work.

Comment: I would think the question was voted down because the way it's worded make it seem like it seeks a discussion rather than a definitive answer ("Why yes and why no?").